# Authenticate an API Request with OAuth?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to write a C# script to make an API request and store the stream as a json file. I got the following code to work with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com but need to add OAuth authentication to make a request to another site. I already have the public token and secret key. Any help on how to send these with the request would be greatly appreciated. I have installed the Owin.Security.OAuth package but unsure how to use this. I am willing to use a different OAuth package if neccesary. Thanks!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strurltest = String.Format("http://api.fakeWebsite.com/v1/sites.json");
        string public_token = "****************";
        string secret_key = "**************";
        WebRequest requestObject;
        requestObject = WebRequest.Create(strurltest);        
        requestObject.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse responseObject = null;
        responseObject = (HttpWebResponse)requestObject.GetResponse();
        string strresulttest = null;
        using (Stream stream = responseObject.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            strresulttest = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }

        JObject json = JObject.Parse(strresulttest);

        using (StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter(@"E:\Programs\ApiRequests\" + "Comments" + ".json"))
        {
            myFile.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented));
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Using DevDefined.OAuth NuGet package I create  new OAuthConsumerContext object and assign the consumerkey and consumersecret values to its same name variables. Then I just create a OAuthSession object, passing the ConsumerContext object as an arguement. Finally I make a session.Request.Get().ForURl() call and pass the site api url as an argument.

Hope this helps the next person.